# Inversion of conics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, mobius-transformation

The following cardoids  are obtained by inverting conics of Newtonian polar form $ (r\rightarrow a^2/r), a=1 $, about a focus of variable eccentricity $e=(0.5,0.8,5/4,4/3,3/2). $

$$ \dfrac{a}{r}=\dfrac{1-e \cos \theta}{1-e^2}$$

Can the $e$ be interpreted geometrically on the cardoids without reference to the un-inverted  conic?

[image]

Comment: The curves intersect $x$ axis at $x=\pm1/(1\pm e)$.

Comment: i meant $e$ as a property of the cardoid...

Comment: But that IS a property of the cardioid.